# Can't access my external HDD

Tags: linux-mint

My external 4TB hard drive (that I previously used on Windows 10) has been reformatted to ext4 with a label of 4TB, but I can't transfer my files to it; no proper permission.

I want to be able to use this HDD like any other hard drive without exception. I've read a number of posts on this site and others, but answers are usually all different, do not work in my case, or are so involved that an old duffer like me might have a hard time effecting such advice.

How can I read and write to his HD without jumping through procedural hoops? Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to write a file to it?

Comment: And show us how you tried to write to the file. (put both of these in the question, do note amend via comments).

Comment: My error message is as follows: Error while copying “1 – Of Interest.odt”. Therre was an error copying the file into /media/harvey/4TB * Show more details  Error opening file ‘/media/harvey/4TB/1 – Of Interest.odt’: Permission denied.  I'm still afraid of the terminal so I drag and drop all of my files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the ownership and/or group of the USB drive's mount-point (and all files/dirs in it, if any) so that your user can read and write to it.

Alternatively (or additionally), you could change the permissions so that ANY USER can read or write to it.

In short, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo chown -R user:group /path/to/usb/mount
```

and/or:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwX /path/to/usb/mount
```

**Details**:

So, if your username is `harvey` and your group is also `harvey`, and the USB drive is mounted on `/media/usb` you would run:

```
sudo chown -R harvey:harvey /media/usb
```

The `-R` option tells `chown` to change the ownership of ALL existing files and sub-directories below that path.  If the USB disk is empty, it can be omitted.

And to change the permissions so that ANY USER can read and write the files:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwX /media/usb
```

This sets the read and write bits (`rw`) for ALL users for all files and directories in `/media/usb`,  and also sets the executable bit (`X`, not capital X, not lowercase) for all directories (and existing executable files - programs and scripts).

The `-R` option has the same meaning (recursive change) as for `chown`.

NOTE: if there are multiple users on this system, they will ALL be able to read and write all files.  This is probably not what you want.  If you want to share the USB drive with other users while still being able to have your own private files and dirs, run this instead:

```
sudo mkdir /media/usb/harvey
sudo chown harvey:harvey /media/usb/harvey
sudo chmod 770 /media/usb/harvey
```

Other users can have their own directories in `/media/usb`, owned by them and their groups.

You can also make a shared directory (e.g. `/media/usb/shared`) and `chmod` it with `777` permissions instead of `770` to allow all users to read and write in that dir.

---

Some (or perhaps even all) of this can be done from your GUI file-browser, but the details depend on exactly which file browser you're using, what features it has, and if it has some method of performing some operations as `root` (and if so, exactly which method of gaining root privileges - it varies widely).

It's easier to just do it from the command line.  Certainly easier and shorter to describe how to do it.

Comment: Your recommendation worked beautifully. But upon initiating those terminal commands a bunch of folders, once hidden, have appeared in the treeview panel under the Home directory, like .adobe, .cache, .cinnamon, .config, .dbud, .dvdcss, etc. How can I hide these folders?

Comment: the commands above had absolutely nothing to do with hidden files in your home directory appearing in your GUI file browser.  They don't do **anything** to your home dir or to your file browser's config.  You must have been doing something else (like editing preferences or maybe an upgrade) around the same time.  Hiding them again is file-browser dependent, look in its preferences or settings dialog for a related option.

Answer (score 0):

As you have formatted this drive with an ext4 filesystem which uses user and group ids for basic access control, you need to change the owner or group of the filesystem's root directory so that you can write to it. As creating a filesystem is normally done as user "root", your normal user most likely does not have those permissions.

Comment: Yes, that's it. But how does one get the required permissions? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose it's your own system, so you can become root. As root you can change the permissions of the filesystem as needed.